# Exception thrown while starting JBoss 6

Tags: eclipse, java-ee-6, jboss6.x

When I start JBoss 6 through Eclipse (Helios) without deploying any application it starts without a problem. When I deploy my ear it throws the following exception which does not reference my project at all. Any help would be appreciated.

```
WARN  [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.xml.JSTLXPathNamespaceContext: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext"
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27-ea]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [:1.6.0_27-ea]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [:1.6.0_27-ea]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27-ea]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:260) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1152) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) [:1.6.0_27-ea]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_27-ea]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) [:1.6.0_27-ea]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.resolveComplexTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:458) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.getTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactoryImpl.java:414) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.IntrospectionTypeInfoFactory.getTypeInfo(IntrospectionTypeInfoFactory.java:54) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.config.plugins.AbstractConfiguration.getTypeInfo(AbstractConfiguration.java:121) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.config.AbstractKernelConfig.getTypeInfo(AbstractKernelConfig.java:95) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.config.AbstractKernelConfigurator.getTypeInfo(AbstractKernelConfigurator.java:102) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ConfiguratorReflectProvider.getTypeInfo(ConfiguratorReflectProvider.java:47) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.CachingReflectProvider.getTypeInfo(CachingReflectProvider.java:52) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.getTypeInfo(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:60) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.getClassInfo(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:72) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.doVisit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:107) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.visitor.ReflectResourceVisitor.visit(ReflectResourceVisitor.java:86) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.scanning.hierarchy.plugins.HierarchyIndexScanningPlugin.visit(HierarchyIndexScanningPlugin.java:91) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.ScanningPluginWrapper.visit(ScanningPluginWrapper.java:112) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.visitor.FederatedResourceVisitor.visit(FederatedResourceVisitor.java:101) [jboss-classloading.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:264) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:408) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:410) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.visit(VirtualFile.java:396) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.classloading.plugins.vfs.VFSResourceVisitor.visit(VFSResourceVisitor.java:102) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.plugins.classloader.VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.visit(VFSDeploymentClassLoaderPolicyModule.java:181) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.scanning.plugins.DeploymentUnitScanner.scan(DeploymentUnitScanner.java:111) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.scanning.spi.helpers.UrlScanner.scan(UrlScanner.java:96) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.scanning.deployers.ScanningDeployer.deploy(ScanningDeployer.java:95) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1603) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.deploy(ProfileDeployAction.java:151) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileDeployAction.installActionInternal(ProfileDeployAction.java:94) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper$BasicProfileActivation.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:190) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationWrapper.start(ProfileActivationWrapper.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activateProfile(ProfileActivationService.java:215) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileActivationService.activate(ProfileActivationService.java:159) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.activate(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:112) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.resolver.BasicResolverFactory$ProfileResolverFacade.deploy(BasicResolverFactory.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.bootstrap.AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.start(AbstractProfileServiceBootstrap.java:91) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:132) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(AbstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_27-ea]
```

Comment: Can you list the libraries in your ear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I removed the two JSTL jars of the web project from WEB-INF/lib (jstl-api-1.2.jar and jstl-impl-1.2.jar) and there are no errors.